# Cocoa-Touch: How to set the interpolation quality to be used by a UIImageView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-graphics

I have a `UIImageView` showing a image that is larger than it's frame.
It's set to rescale the image to fit it's frame. But, the image is scaled with a low quality filter.

I've [read here](http://vocaro.com/trevor/blog/2009/10/12/resize-a-uiimage-the-right-way/) that this is caused by it using a low interpolation quality.

How can I get it's context to `CGContextSetInterpolationQuality` to `kCGInterpolationHigh`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UIImageView does not offer this functionality, though UIImage has an undocumented `_imageScaledToSize:interpolationQuality:` method if I remember correctly.

Since UIImageView draws directly to the display, subclassing and overriding `drawRect:` is no option (thanks to Prody for pointing this out). The only option I see is to create a custom UIView subclass with a custom `drawrect:` implementation.

Comment: From the docs: The UIImageView class is optimized to draw its images to the display. UIImageView will not call drawRect:. I can't find any  mention of _imageScaledToSize:interpolationQuality. I guess for now I'll draw my image in the parent view's drawRect.

Comment: Thanks for the correction, Prody. I should have read the docs before posting. I will edit my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

From "[UIImageView scaling/interpolation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191868/uiimageview-scaling-interpolation)", this is the most streamlined way to do it if you can:

```
[[yourimageview layer] setMagnificationFilter:kCAFilterTrilinear]
```

Be sure to `#import <QuartzCore/CALayer.h>`

A warning on kCAFilterTrilinear: "Some renderers may ignore this, or impose additional restrictions, such as source images requiring power-of-two dimensions."

Answer (score 1):

CGContextSetInterpolationQuality is a function. You need to call it with whatever parameters are appropriate for your situation.

http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/qa/qa2001/qa1186.html

Comment: And where do you call this function to apply it to the UIImageView's drawing?

Comment: I'd draw the image into a new context using this setting, take the resulting UIImage, and set the UIImageView.image property to the refined image.